# How to save/retrieve password from iOS Autofill Password?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, keychain, autofill

I'm trying to implement Apple's Autofill Password. I finally got it working, but I want my app to remember the username/password on app launch if credentials were indeed created. I'm currently storing username and password using the 'KeychainSwift' pod, but I realized that Autofill creates a new keychain anyway (they now appear in my iPhone Saved Passwords), so I might as well use those credentials directly. 
I tried retrieving it with this, but says "no matching items found":

```
SecRequestSharedWebCredential(nil, nil){ credentials, error in
        guard let credentials = credentials else { print("Keychain: No credentials found"); return }
        guard error == nil else { print("Keychain Error:", error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error description"); return }

        let credential: CFDictionary = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(credentials, i), to: CFDictionary.self)
        let server = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(credential, unsafeBitCast(kSecAttrServer, to: UnsafeRawPointer<Void>.self)), to: CFString.self)
        let account = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(credential, unsafeBitCast(kSecAttrAccount, to: UnsafeRawPointer<Void>.self)), to: CFString.self)
        let password = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(credential, unsafeBitCast(kSecSharedPassword, to: UnsafeRawPointer<Void>.self)), to: CFString.self)

        print("Keychain OK:", server, account, password)
    }
```

The request stops executing at the second guard statement because 'error' is not nil. Am I missing something? Is this at all possible?

**Edit #1**:
I've been reading up on all of this, and I'm getting the feeling I have to separately save/load the username/password combination (either through Keychain or UserDefaults) whenever the user signs up or logins. Can anyone confirm that this is the expected behavior? Just seems weird to me, as Autofill already stores these credentials somewhere (I assumed the Keychain), since FaceID pops up and autofills the textfields with the correct username/password I provided during Sign up.

**Edit #2**:
**This is what I'd like to ideally achieve**: an Autofill option on the keyboard's QuickType, and when a user signs up/in to add it to the saved passwords that appear in Settings > Passwords & Account > Website & App Passwords". Maybe I'm failing to understand the actual flow of Autofill, or the difference between iCloud keychain and shared web credentials, but I can't wrap my head around how to achieve what I need.

Instead, so many **unexpected things (bugs?) happen**: tapping Autofill creates new credentials automatically, but I can't retrieve them with the code I posted above, yet if I manually add it with `SecAddSharedWebCredential()` I can then retrieve them. Why? They literally both appear in my saved passwords, under the same domain, with the same app icon. Also, when the Signin ViewController gets dismissed (performing a Segue) I get prompted to Save Password, but the moment I try to Signup with a username + strongly suggested password then pressed Back (which dismisses the ViewController), it still adds it to the Saved passwords, this time without even prompting me to Save the password!

I am so confused by all of this lol. Please, I need help :)

Comment: The way that I understand it is that we never get direct access to the passwords - this is the point of the way that Apple have implemented it.

The user can (if they want to) enter the password in a textField etc, but I don't think they're stored anywhere where we can access them directly. Think of the security implications of developers just being able to harvest passwords from the keychain!

Comment: save user password in prefs using for username as key, and access it when user enters the username and set it in textField.

Comment: @ Abu, so you're suggesting storing the password myself, gotcha.
@ siburg, we can access the passwords directly though. With Shared Web Credentials, if I use SecAddSharedWebCredential( ) to set the credentials, I can then have access to the password by calling SecRequestSharedWebCredential( ). I'm just confused as to why I have to explicitly call SecAddSharedWebCredential( ) if it automatically creates the credentials when ViewController gets dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: You can save/retrieve passwords using Autofill **only if you've manually added them** with `SecAddSharedWebCredential()`.

Here's what I've learned about the entire process:

Just by enabling Autofill (setting contentType to `.username` and `.password`/`.newPassword`, as well as adding an Associated Domain), the app automatically prompts to "Save Password?" when the active ViewController gets dismissed if I'm logging in or signing up *with my own password* (kinda cool that I don't need to add any code to have these credentials added to the iCloud Keychain). If I'm signing up with Apple's "Strong Password", however, when my active ViewController gets dismissed (i.e. by tapping the Back button, using the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, or even completing the sign up successfully), **it automatically adds the credentials to the iCloud Keychain without even showing the "Save Password?" prompt (no user knowledge or consent). I feel like this should not be happening**, so I've just submitted a bug.

Now, when the credentials are added *automatically*, we cannot retrieve the password with the expected function `SecRequestSharedWebCredential(nil,nil)`: no credentials will be found. **We can only retrieve a password if we've manually added it with `SecAddSharedWebCredential()`** (which I also find a bit like weird behavior, since the end results is exactly the same). But this is not what I wanted, since `SecAddSharedWebCredential()`'s prompt is different and too wordy, and `SecRequestSharedWebCredential()` also shows a prompt even though I wanted to retrieve it silently (say, by storing the username in UserDefaults and retrieving it with `SecRequestSharedWebCredential(nil, username)`.

*Conclusion: I couldn't do what I wanted (use iCloud Keychain to save and silently retrieve the right credentials, without needing a copy in my own app Keychain). I ended up separately storing username/hash on my app Keychain for automatic login, and I've kept Autofill enabled for a quick Login in case the user needs to temporarily logout (which removes username/hash from my app Keychain) while having saved the password in iCloud Keychain.*

Answer (score -2):

You should not store username and password. When user is logged for first time, you should generate token. Token should be stored in yours app Keychain. When user starts your app for second time, you should use the token to login.

Storing token is much safer than storing username and password.

If you want store the password then at least store just password hash not the plain text.

Comment: Even storing the password hash isn’t the best. If anything hash and salt it.

Comment: I mention 'password' to make the argument simpler, as the problem is already quite complicated. I'm looking for suggestions on how to deal with autofill and the credentials it uses (saving and retrieving them).